# List of dicts, group without intersection by list keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I need help to optimize my code.

I have a data:

```
data = [
  {"ids": [1]},
  {"ids": [3, 4]},
  {"ids": [1, 2]},
  {"ids": [2]},
]
```

and I need to group it without intersection by ids, so expected data should be:

```
expected = [
  [{"ids": [1]}, {"ids": [2]}],
  [{"ids": [3, 4]}, {"ids": [1, 2]}],
]  # only 2 sublist here
```

My code to split(not optimized):

```
import itertools as it

def _split(
    list_of_dicts,
):
    splitted_list_of_dicts = []
    sub_list = []
    while list_of_dicts:
        for dct in list_of_dicts:
            ids_in_sub_list = set(
                it.chain(*[sub_list_el["ids"] for sub_list_el in sub_list]),
            )
            if not set(dct["ids"]).intersection(ids_in_sub_list):
                sub_list.append(dct)
                list_of_dicts.remove(dct)
        splitted_list_of_dicts.append(sub_list)
        sub_list = []
    return splitted_list_of_dicts
```

The result of my code is:

```
result = [
    [{'ids': [1]}, {'ids': [2]}],
    [{'ids': [3, 4]}],
    [{'ids': [1, 2]}]
]  # 3 sublist
```

I get one more list, which I try to optimize.
If you have any ideas on how to help me, I'll be happy, thanks for your time.

More examples:

```
data = [
  {"ids": [1]},
  {"ids": [3, 4]},
  {"ids": [1, 2]},
  {"ids": [4]},
  {"ids": [3]},
  {"ids": [2]},
]
```

can be grouped as 2 elements list:

```
expected = [
    [{'ids': [1]}, {'ids': [4]}, {'ids': [2]}, {'ids': [3]}],
    [{'ids': [3, 4]}, {'ids': [1, 2]}],
]
```

but now I got all 4:

```
result = [
    [{'ids': [1]}, {'ids': [4]}, {'ids': [2]}],
    [{'ids': [3, 4]}],
    [{'ids': [1, 2]}],
    [{'ids': [3]}]
]
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that you always have an even number of elements in the given input?

Comment: No, it's just an example data. Number of elements can be any.

Comment: Do you have more examples? I'm still not sure how you're expected to group the data.

Comment: So you want to look at _all data_ and make the best possible grouping that doesn't have any intersecting id?

Comment: what's the reason `[1, 2] and [3, 4]` are grouped together?

Comment: > what's the reason [1, 2] and [3, 4] are grouped together?

they are grouped cuz they has no intersection by elements

Comment: Why, in your "can be grouped as 3 elements list" example, could we not make just two groups `[(1), (2), (3), (4)]; [(1, 2), (3, 4)]`?

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed, yes, it can be grouped even as 2 elements list:
`[[{'ids': [1]}, {'ids': [4]}, {'ids': [2]}, {'ids': [3]}], [{'ids': [3, 4]}, {'ids': [1, 2]}]]`

Comment: So are both acceptable answers, or is it just one of the two? @Vladimir What about `[(1), (3, 4), (2)]` and `[(1, 2), (4), (3)]` for that example?

Comment: both answers are acceptable, main purpose is split list of dicts on smallest amount of elements @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any combination that doesn't contain duplicates is acceptable, you could simply iterate over the `data` list and append the current element to the first element in the result where none of the ids already exist.

```
def split(list_of_dicts):
    result_helper = [set()] # This will be a list of sets for easy membership checks
    result_list = [[]] # This will be what we return
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        for s, l, in zip(result_helper, result_list):
            if not any(x in s for x in d["ids"]):
                s.update(d["ids"])
                l.append(d)
                break
        else:
            # for loop ended without being broken
            # This means no elements of result_list took this dict item. 
            # So create a new element
            result_list.append([d])
            result_helper.append(set(d["ids"]))
    return result_list
```

With your original data,

```
data = [
  {"ids": [1]},
  {"ids": [3, 4]},
  {"ids": [1, 2]},
  {"ids": [2]},
]
split(data)
```

we get the output:

```
 [
    [{'ids': [1]}, {'ids': [3, 4]}, {'ids': [2]}],
    [{'ids': [1, 2]}]
 ]
```

which seems to be an acceptable solution because none of the lists have a duplicated id.

And with the second example:

```py
data = [
  {"ids": [1]},
  {"ids": [3, 4]},
  {"ids": [1, 2]},
  {"ids": [4]},
  {"ids": [3]},
  {"ids": [2]},
]
split(data)
```

This gives the output:

```
 [
    [{'ids': [1]}, {'ids': [3, 4]}, {'ids': [2]}],
    [{'ids': [1, 2]}, {'ids': [4]}, {'ids': [3]}]
 ]
```

No duplicates in this case either.

Comment: Thanks, man, you are kind of genius. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your question, you are essentially sorting the ids on each group's cardinality.

```
from itertools import groupby


def transform(data):
    cardinality = lambda x: len(x['ids'])
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=cardinality)
    return [list(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted_data, key=cardinality)]
```

Giving:

```
[
    [
        {'ids': [1]},
        {'ids': [4]},
        {'ids': [3]},
        {'ids': [2]}
    ],
    [
        {'ids': [3, 4]},
        {'ids': [1, 2]}
    ]
]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time, but I need to save my original dicts.

Comment: if we use data like:
`[
  {"ids": [1]},
  {"ids": [3, 4]},
  {"ids": [1, 2]},
  {"ids": [5]},
  {"ids": [3]},
  {"ids": [2]},
  {"ids": [2, 3]},
]`
the result data will be with duplicates: `[{'ids': [[1], [5], [3], [2]]}, {'ids': [[3, 4], [1, 2], [2, 3]]}]`

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but I think I got it now. Learned a bit too.